# Is there a website that compares the features of different cryptocoins?

Tags: alternatives, altcoin

Is there any website where I can find a comparison of different altcoins by features?

I'm not interested in hashrate, price, difficulty, but rather in implemented features such as:

- Used difficulty retargeting algorithm
- Anonymous blockchain
- Encrypted transaction network

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest you get is [this list of all cryptocoins on Bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=3m18crc564mqjhds1i072bb7j5&topic=134179.0). There is a very brief summery of features there, but you can click further to the corresponding official thread, which should contain all information available on the altcoin.

Sadly, almost none have a thorough explanation of the algorithms involved and are hard to access without looking through the entire code (if available at all). I'm even a bit disappointed in Bitcoin in this case. I have yet to see a javadoc like thorough code documentation for any cryptocoin.